# How to cconcatenate input to LSTM

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, lstm

I have one input for the embedding layer and another input for the sentiment score feature.
How can I combine these two inputs in the model and feed them into an LSTM?

I'm a novice in deep learning, and I'm not sure if the following model design is correct.
I have tried using Concatenate to merge the two inputs, but the performance was not good.

I use `Keras`.
I want to classify the text as either sarcastic(1) or non-sarcastic(0). It's a binary classification task."

```
def create_model():
    input1 = Input(name='text', shape=[max_len])

    layer = Embedding(
        max_words,
        embedding_dim,
        weights=[embedding_matrix],
        input_length=max_len,
        trainable=False
    )(input1)

    input2 = Input(name='sent',shape=(1,))
    expanded_sent = RepeatVector(max_len)(input2)
    
    concat_feature = Concatenate()([layer,expanded_sent])

    lstm_layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(64))(concat_feature)
    drop_layer = Dropout(0.4)(lstm_layer)

    # Output layer.
    out_layer = Dense(1, name='out_layer', activation='sigmoid')(drop_layer)
    model = Model(inputs=[input1,input2], outputs=out_layer)
    return model


model = create_model()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.01), metrics=['accuracy'])

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0.001, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='min', restore_best_weights=True)

history = model.fit(
    [sequences_matrix,x_train_sent],
    y_train,
    batch_size=64,
    epochs=100,
    validation_split=0.1,
    callbacks=[early_stopping]
)

__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 text (InputLayer)           [(None, 150)]                0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 sent (InputLayer)           [(None, 1)]                  0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 embedding_42 (Embedding)    (None, 150, 100)             100000    ['text[0][0]']                
                                                                                                  
 repeat_vector_14 (RepeatVe  (None, 150, 1)               0         ['sent[0][0]']                
 ctor)                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
 concatenate_40 (Concatenat  (None, 150, 101)             0         ['embedding_42[0][0]',        
 e)                                                                  'repeat_vector_14[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 bidirectional_17 (Bidirect  (None, 128)                  84992     ['concatenate_40[0][0]']      
 ional)                                                                                           
                                                                                                  
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 128)                  0         ['bidirectional_17[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 out_layer (Dense)           (None, 1)                    129       ['dropout_1[0][0]']           
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 185121 (723.13 KB)
Trainable params: 85121 (332.50 KB)
Non-trainable params: 100000 (390.62 KB)
```

Comment: Please edit the post with more information. Is the library `Pytorch` or `Keras`? Is the task text classification? If the code works without an error but the performance is bad, maybe the combination of the textual with the numerical feature worked, but they are just not very informative features for the task.